# Android Jetpack compose with ModalBottomSheet causing memory leak

Tags: android, kotlin, memory-leaks, android-jetpack-compose

I'm trying to use `MosalBottomSheet` with jetpack compose, but when I try to close it programatically (and not by just pressing outside the bottom sheet) it cause a memory leak in the app and I keep seeing this logs being printed without stopping:

```
Explicit concurrent copying GC freed 336(48KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 49% free, 9096KB/17MB, paused 217us,66us total 103.567ms
```

**I see this log starting when I close the bottom sheet programatically, and not if I close it by just pressing outside the bottom sheet.**

**So I guess my problem is somewhere in the way I display and hide the ModalBottomSheet.**

This is my code to display the bottom sheet:

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class, ExperimentalFoundationApi::class)
@Composable
fun TestScreen(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
) {
    val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()
    val bottomSheetState = rememberModalBottomSheetState(
        skipPartiallyExpanded = false
    )
    
    if (bottomSheetState.isVisible) {
        BottomSheetContent(
            bottomSheetState = bottomSheetState,
            modifier = modifier
        )
    }
    
    Column(
            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
        ) {
        Button(
            onClick = {
                    coroutineScope.launch {
                        bottomSheetState.expand()
                    }
                }
        ) {
            Text("Open bottom sheet")
        }
    }

}
```

And this is my bottom sheet composable with the hide option:

```
@Composable
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
fun BottomSheetContent(
    modifier: Modifier,
    bottomSheetState: SheetState,
) {
    val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()
    
    ModalBottomSheet(
        onDismissRequest = {
            coroutineScope.launch {
                bottomSheetState.hide()
            }
        },
        sheetState = bottomSheetState,
    ) {
        Button(
            onClick = {
                    coroutineScope.launch {
                        bottomSheetState.hide()
                    }
                }
        ) {
            Text("Close bottom sheet")
        }
    }
}
```

So, when I press the `"Close bottom sheet"` button it does close the bottom sheet, but it also starts printing the log messages without stopping, and te leak canary starts to display leak messages.

I tried to find an example on how to work with ModalBottomSheet on material3 but couldn't find anything.

any idea what am I missing?
thanks

Comment: Did you figure this out ? I have a problem with modal bottom sheet consuming back presses even after it has been collapsed/hidden which seems to indicate it is still in memory.

Comment: @A.Sanchez.SD no I haven't...

Comment: I have gotten good results with bottom sheet as nav destination through accompanist framework https://google.github.io/accompanist/navigation-material/